# Is it possible to run raw (native) SQL with nano-sql

Tags: javascript, sql, nano-sql

I can't find anywhere in the documentation a way to execute a raw SQL string with [nanoSQL](https://docs.nanosql.io/setup). If not possible could anyone recommend another in-memory SQL solution where I can run raw SQLs?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible. Also, asking for recommendations is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also seems impossible to me. Couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sqlite. While it supports most standard functionalities of a RDBMS, it has a setting that allows the database to be stored in memory only. See [the sqlite documentation](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, sqlite cannot be plugged into a nodesql in-memory app

Answer (score 0):

Library author here, it's not possible to do this since nanoSQL has it's own query language.

However, this is a planned feature for nanoSQL 2.0.  Keep an eye on the readme.md in this repo under "Query Support"
https://github.com/ClickSimply/Nano-SQL